# Useless tag: "learning"

Tags: discussion, tags

I found a tag that looks useless: [learning](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning). There are currently only 16 questions with that tag. I think it is a useless tag because it is too general. Nearly all questions on this site are about "learning". We already have [financial-literacy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-literacy) that covers part of "learning". Should "learning" be removed?